# Редирект 301 в зависимости от ГЕО и типа устройства

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

У меня есть веб-сайт. На нём есть ссылки редиректа на другой ресурс. Сайт написан на PHP и за редирект отвечает контроллер с простым экшеном, (`actionIndex`) в котором просто `header Location:...` (грубо говоря)

Как, в зависимости от ГЕО + устройства сделать редирект по клику на эту же ссылку, на другой ресурс?

Пример.

Ссылка /visit-me - в обычном случае ведет на www . мой-сайт . ru

В случае с ПК + ГЕО Россия - www . не-мой-сайт . ru

Answer (score 0):

Получение геолокационных данных по IP адресу [тут](https://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php)
и получение информации об устройстве через [HTTP_USER_AGENT](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), либо библиотеки типа [Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/)

[Источник / source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646918/get-specific-device-information)